# Jquery: Execute a jquery function after load a innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to execute a simple click function after a InnerHTML is created, but it's not working. None is showed in console.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lorum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, leo nulla ipsum vivamus, augue tempor inceptos sed nam rhoncus. Rhoncus montes litora. Praesent ut ad ornare fusce posuere in, libero bibendum, et adipiscing. <a href='#' id='hue'> You can click here </a>";

  $('button').click(function() {
    $('#content').html(lorum);
  });

  $(function() {
    $('#hue').click(function() {
      $('#content-2').html(lorum);
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button>Generate</button> <br><br>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="content-2"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: You are attaching two event listeners to some items, in order for anything to happen you have to trigger the listeners (in this case by clicking the elements)

Comment: Can you show me?

Comment: Not really, if you want `<div id="content"></div>` to have innerHTML of lorum, click the button

Comment: You bind the event to an element BEFORE it exists. It is like ordering delivery food and trying to eat it before it is given to you. Not going to happen. So you need to either bind it when you add the element, or you need to use event delegation to listen for the element at a different place in the DOM. `$(document).on("click", '#hue', function() { console.log("BAM"); } );`

Comment: Thanks @epascarello

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lorum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, leo nulla ipsum vivamus, augue tempor inceptos sed nam rhoncus. Rhoncus montes litora. Praesent ut ad ornare fusce posuere in, libero bibendum, et adipiscing. <a href='#' id='hue'> You can click here </a>";
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('#content').html(lorum);
    $('#hue').click(function() {
      console.log("clicked a");
      $('#content2').html(lorum);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button>Generate</button> <br><br>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="content2"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tweak your code a little bit.

Here's the script:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var lorum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, leo nulla ipsum vivamus, augue tempor 
  inceptos sed nam rhoncus. Rhoncus montes litora. Praesent ut ad ornare fusce posuere 
  in, libero bibendum, et adipiscing. <a href='#' id='hue'> You can click here </a>";

  $('button').click(function(){
    $('#content').html(lorum);
    $('#hue').click(); //the trigger
  });

  $(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#hue',function() { //the listener
        $('#content-2').html(lorum); 
    });
  });
```

After clicking the `<button>` you need to trigger the `#hue` to be clicked.

Then there is an event click listener for `#hue`. You need to use jquery `on()` method not just `click()` because the `#hue` is not present after the DOM loads.

Please refer to this link for more info.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var lorum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, leo nulla ipsum vivamus, augue tempor inceptos sed nam rhoncus. Rhoncus montes litora. Praesent ut ad ornare fusce posuere in, libero bibendum, et adipiscing. <a href='#' id='hue'> You can click here </a>";

      $('button').click(function(){
        $('#content').html(lorum);
      });

      $(function() {
        $('#hue').click(function() {
            $('#content-2').html(lorum); 
        });
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>
 <body>
  <button>Generate</button> <br><br>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="content-2"></div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

### Just Replace the Script into Header

I Shift Your Script into Header Section

Comment: That is not going to make a difference....